# SQL Server Standalone and Sharepoint connected to a domain

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, active-directory, sql-server

I am currently in the process of setting up a client that wishes to use SharePoint. They currently have a Enterprise version of SQL Server 2012 running in a standalone environment and is not connected to a domain.  They want to install Share point and connect it to the domain and use the Standalone SQL Server for the sharepoint installation.

What i'm asking is this possible or does the SQL Server have to be joined to the domain?

Comment: can you access the SQL server from other servers then itself?

Comment: Yes it is accessible.

Comment: How you access it from outside SEVER, i am sure you are using SSMS to connect it...what authentication you used

Comment: I haven't used anything to connect to it yet.  This is a new client and they are asking me if this type of environment will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using non-domain account for installing and configuring SharePoint will result in ending up with only ONE web server and ONE database - that's it - NO splitting of roles in the WFE, and NO redundancy support, and you CAN'T add more servers.

But if your SharePoint servers are on Domain but SQL server is non-domain **but available on the network then you can use SQL Authentication to connect the SQL server.** But again their are limitation in this type, you cannot use the User Profile Sync services.

You have to manually run the Config wizard 1st via command line then from GUI. here are commands for it.

```
    PSConfig -cmd -configdb -create -server database_servername -database SharePoint_Config -user domain/username -password password 
-dbuser sharepoint_login_username -dbpassword sharepoint_login_password -admincontentdatabase SharePoint_AdminContent
```

The arguments for:

- server - this would be your SQL Database Server's Instance name
- database - the database name for SharePoint's configuration (we name
  it SharePoint_Config here)
- user - the windows account used as the server farm's administrator
  account
- dbuser - the SQL login account to connect to the database
- admincontentdatabase - the database name for SharePoint's Central
  Administration site (SharePoint_AdminContent)

Comment: Looks like User Profile Sync Services can be used with SQL Authentication based on this article.  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/6232cbea-10f3-4291-8d07-752682cf2bad/sharepoint-2013-installation-with-sql-server-authentication?forum=sharepointadmin 

You need to install KB2752001, KB2752058, and then KB2767999 on the server, User Profile Synchronization Service can be started using SQL Authentication successfully. Please note that the server needs to be restarted after installing the hotfix and we need to run SharePoint configuration Wizard to finish the upgrade.

Comment: which articles, Because FIM Engine required the Windows Authentication. You get the User Profile instance but not sync. we are in the same boat due to some firewall rules..:)

Comment: I am not sure, none of the KB article talked about the sync with SQL auth